# Execute an activity within an Async task

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Implementing AsyncCodeActivity. Inside of BeginExecute, I want to create a new task and within that task execute a CodeActivity. Something like this:

```
public class Working : AsyncCodeActivity
{
public NativeActivity nativeAct = new NativeActiv....

protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyAsyncCodeActivityContext c, AsyncCallback c, object s)
{    
    Task executeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(  
        /* THIS IS MY QUESTION - how do I execute "nativeAct" here? Something like nativeAct.execute(), but it won't let me do that */
    );    
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with act.Execute? Where is the code and where is the error message?

Comment: ```Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });```

Comment: nativeAct.Execute will not work as Execute is a protected method inside of the native activity. This question is more about Workflow / Activities than tasks really.

Comment: [WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(nativeAct)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987473(v=vs.110).aspx)? Am I missing something?